# Defining Vue.js template aliases

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, webpack, vue.js

I have a front-end project laid out like so:

```
resources/assets/js
resources/assets/jade
resources/assets/svg
resources/assets/sass
```

I have recently found out that it is possible to define aliases in webpack to prevent the constant use of relative paths like `../../../..` by providing them in the `resolve.alias` map. Now my imports in Javascript are much simpler to understand. However, I've tried doing something similar for my Jade templates, defined like this:

```
<template lang="jade">
    include ../../../jade/pages/home

    .component-class
        +home-item
</template>
```

Instead of writing `../../../jade/pages/home`, I'd like to write `pages/home` but can't see any documented way of doing so. Is this possible? This is something I'd like to do with `sass-loader` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely do this.  I wish the [docs](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html) were more clear about this as it's pretty important for a large pug app.

Add this to your app.js/server.js:

```
app.locals.basedir = path.join(__dirname, 'views');
```

Then you can reference all template files using a leading backslash character, for example:

```
include /pages/administrator/home
include /mixins/widget
```